# Don't hold back

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, wordplay

> My first is employed all the time by a plumber.
>   It's seen by the poolside, most often in summer.
>
> For a surgeon, my second will help with dilation,
>   But then will get pitched when she goes on vacation.
>
> My third was a cow, if the legends are true,
>   And denser than all of its brethren, too.
>
> My last part is hidden between you and me
>   In the land of the brave and the home of the free.
>
> My whole isn't likely to say what it thinks,
>   And surely won't join you in having a drink.
>
> The word is quite special, I'm sure you'll agree
>   For a bonus, explain its uniqueness to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My whole isn't likely to say what it thinks,
And surely won't join you in having a drink.

The answer is:

> [Abstentious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abstentious)

My first is employed all the time by a plumber.
It's seen by the poolside, most often in summer.

> Abs.  The easy definition is the summer one.  Plumbers often use PVC or ABS pipes, I believe ABS stands for [Acrylonitrile butadiene styrene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylonitrile_butadiene_styrene)

For a surgeon, my second will help with dilation,
But then will get pitched when she goes on vacation.

> Tent.  This can be used to cause blood vessels to dilate as well as the more traditional meaning.

My third was a cow, if the legends are true,
And denser than all of its brethren, too.

> Io has the highest density of all of [Jupiter's moons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_(moon)) as well as a person [Zeus transformed into a cow to hide from Hera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_(mythology))

My last part is hidden between you and me
In the land of the brave and the home of the free.

> US.  You and me makes US, as well as the United States.

The word is quite special, I'm sure you'll agree
For a bonus, explain its uniqueness to me.

> As, [alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja) convinced me, although not completely unique, this word does have every vowel in order which deserves mention.

Comment: Ahh.. beaten by a minute. Was just typing it in. :)

Comment: Could you add an explanation for "abs"?

Comment: @randal'thor just did when I realized I overlooked it.  Not sure about why the word is unique...

Comment: The word is unique because it contains all the vowels in order.

Comment: @Alconja It's *facetious* to think that makes this word unique ;-)

Comment: @Alconja thought that, but as rand al'thor pointed out so do other words

Comment: @randal'thor - What an *arsenious* comment to make, completely *facedinous* (ok, the metaphor has been stretched a bit thin now :P).

Comment: @qwertylpc - True, but it's still a very uncommon property (if not quite technically unique to this word), which I imagine is still the intended solution.

Comment: my goal is to answer one of these types of puzzles! eventually it must happen. with each one it seems i learn techniques from everyone. thx.

Comment: @Alconja, this is in fact the *longest* English word containing exactly one of each vowel, in order.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Unless you count *abstentiously* :P

Comment: @Alconja, you're assuming that *abstentiously* is a word, which I don't believe it is.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain _abstemiously_ is though :)

Comment: @PlayerOne, you got me there. I should have done my research better.